Sharepoint Links in Excel break upon copying to new sheet
I have an Excel sheet with about 500 links (created using the copy link button on the browser UI) to various files stored on a company-provided sharepoint account. When I try to copy the sheet contents to a different excel sheet created on a different sharepoint account, the links give a 404 error message on clicking. This happens whether I try using Excel Online or the desktop app.
On investigating it seems the links aren't stored as URLs but as some kind of relative link. If I use the Links button on Excel online it shows the full link to the file, but if I open the link editor on the Excel desktop app the link is incomplete, it shows some kind of partial link like
../../../:u:/p/(user's account name)/(long alphanumeric string)

How do I get direct links to the files back or at least copy the links over in a way that corrects the relative link path or whatever? Doing 500 links by hand is simply not feasible.
